# IIS AppPool Management and Best Practices

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, iis

I make a number of smaller WCF services at work, and many of them are non critical / only contain a few calls.  I have them published to an IIS server each of them to their own 'application'.  Now I have been in the habit of creating a new AppPool for each of these applications, but I wonder if that is really necessary.  I am by no means an IIS expert so I was wondering if there were any pitfalls to my approach that I don't know about?  Or can I just use the DefaultAppPool and still be OK?

Answer (score 3):

We have an AppPool per application for a few reasons. When you change files, the AppPool recycles, or if there is an issue with the AppPool not all applications are at risk.

Our main reasoning for multiple AppPools is security. Each AppPool runs as a different Active Directory account, so if that account becomes compromised other services/applications are not directly vulnerable.

I'm sure you would be "OK" with having them all the same, but from my standpoint the extra 2 minutes it takes to create an AppPool is worth the added flexibility.

Comment: Ok, that seems like a very reasonable approach.  I didn't even think about the benefit of per-pool accounts.

Comment: I agree with your approach, but we have also seen that the assemblies loaded are (of course) not shared between application pools. So all (potentially same and shared) assemblies are loaded at least once in every application pool. If your system can handle that memory load, no problem, but in some cases you might opt to share some related services in an app pool.